# Parameter, if switch is present, don't permit other parameters

Tags: powershell

I have a function with parameters like this:

```
param(
    [string[]]$ComputerName,
    [string]$exepath,
    [string[]]$exeargs,
    [switch]$help
)
```

If the User who uses this function uses the `-help` switch, there must not be any other parameters declared to call the function. I want to prevent anyone using `-help` alongside other parameters.

How can I achieve that? I read [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx) but it doesn't really help me. I first thought what I need is a `ValidateSet` but that's different from what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `ParameterSetName` attribute:

```
param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='default')]
    [string[]]$ComputerName,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='default')]
    [string]$exepath,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='default')]
    [string[]]$exeargs,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='help')]
    [switch]$help
)
```